# open images in a different window with Transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a image which I want to open it in a different window Not a tab window . such as jqm dialog , does any one know how to do that and with transaction effects such as pop ups

here is a sample html

```
        <a id="parispop" href="#popupParis" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="fade"><img class="popphoto" src="images/paris.jpg" alt="Paris, France" style="width:30%"></a>
    <a id="sydnypop" href="#popupSydney" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="fade"><img class="popphoto" src="images/sydney.jpg" alt="Sydney, Australia" style="width:30%"></a>
    <a id="newyorkpop" href="#popupNYC" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="fade"><img class="popphoto" src="images/newyork.jpg" alt="New York, USA" style="width:30%"></a>
```

if it is jquery it will be great (jquery mobile)

please ignore the popup codes

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) function. I usually use it for opening pop up windows.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check the jsFiddle I created. It uses jQuery 1.8.3 and jQuery Mobile 1.2.0.

**HTML Code**

```
<div data-role="page" id="p1"> 
    <div  data-role="header"><h1>Header Page</h1></div> 

    <div  data-role="content" id="imageLists">
        <a href="#view_image" data-role="button"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/93/Cat_poster_2.jpg/297px-Cat_poster_2.jpg" /></a>
    </div> 
    <div  data-role="footer"><h4>Footer</h4></div> 
</div> 


<div data-role="dialog" id="view_image">
    <div  data-role="header" data-rel="back"><h1>Image Container Popup</h1></div>
    <div  data-role="content">
        <p id="image_container"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

> The code below checks the value of the "src" of which item the user clicked, then write it on the #image_container.

```
$(function(){
    $('#imageLists > a').on('click',function(){
        var _img = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        $('#image_container').html('<img src="'+_img+'"/>');
    });
});
```

**jsFiddle Link:** http://jsfiddle.net/dARNs/

Answer (score 0):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/MU26F/

This is a variation of your request. In this example images are sorted on one page and click on it will show it in another page. Page transition chosen is popup. This example can even be smaller if second page is dynamically created and removed after viewer is closed.

**HTML :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
                <h1>Index page</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content" id="galery-content">
                <a id="parispop" href="#"><img class="popphoto" src="http://www.glsvlsi.org/paris_pic.jpg" alt="Paris, France" style="width:30%"/></a>
                <a id="sydnypop" href="#"><img class="popphoto" src="http://sydneylivingtoday.com/public/admin/Sydney-australia.jpg" alt="Sydney, Australia" style="width:30%"/></a>
                <a id="newyorkpop" href="#popupNYC"><img class="popphoto" src="http://www.burgessyachts.com/media/adminforms/locations/n/e/new_york_1.jpg" alt="New York, USA" style="width:30%"/></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="galery">
            <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
                <a href="#index" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>                
                <h1>Viewer</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content" id="image-content">
                <img src="" width="100%" height="auto"/>
            </div>
        </div>          
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#index', function(){ 
    $(document).on('click', '#galery-content a', function(){ 
        $('#image-content img').attr('src',$(this).find('img').attr('src'));
        $.mobile.changePage( "#galery", { transition: "pop", changeHash: false });
    });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#image-content {
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 40px !important;
    left:0 !important;
    bottom:0 !important;
    right:0 !important;
}
```